# How to get Type of generic in Python

Tags: python, generics

```py
EventT = TypeVar('EventT', bound=Event)


class EventSubscriber(Generic[EventT], abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def handle_event(self, ev: EventT) -> None:
        pass

    def subscribed_to_event_type(self) -> Type[EventT]:
        ???


class SampleEvent(Event):
    # snip


class SampleEventSubscriber(EventSubscriber[SampleEvent]):
    # snip
```

I would like to return `SampleEvent` type from `subscribed_to_event_type()` method of `SampleEventSubscriber`.

I don't know how to implement `subscribed_to_event_type()` in `EventSubscriber` class.
Is there any way to get the concrete Type from a generic type (`EventT` in the above code)?

Comment: The typing system is completely optional and not entangled with any runtime logic. So I don't understand what the problem with implementing `subscribed_to_event_type` is. It really depends on your program logic, but when you return a variable with type hint `EventT` it will be just fine.